# How to Odoo backup and restore via terminal for different user?

Tags: ubuntu, odoo, backup, database-backups

I have tow Odoo installed in the same server ubuntu (production - test) every Odoo is with different user.

So i need to write a scripte to make backup from Odoo production with user "production" and restore it in Odoo test with user test.

what i do:

- Copy filestore from production and put it for test.
- and then:
- sudo su production
- pg_dump production > test
- dropdb test
- sudo su test
- createdb test
- psql test < test

but when i run Odoo test i can login and see my module but i can't make any changes.

Would you please tell me how to do backup and restore Odoo for different users via terminal ubuntu?

Thank you